# How do I make footer line up at the bottom of Bootstrap cards component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to work on some CSS and I am using Bootstrap and the component "cards"

When you have them in a class called "card-deck" you can group them to all be the same height. But when one is longer than the other the actual footers in the cards themselves do not align to the bottom of the card.

Is there a way to easily force the footer to the bottom on a shorter card?

[MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rhhy9cjz/)

```css
.row {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Featured
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Featured
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada
              magna mollis euismod. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec sed
              odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is an open issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17134

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use `position:absolute` for footer

```css
.row {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.card-footer{
position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
.card-deck .card{
  padding-bottom:50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Featured
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Featured
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada
              magna mollis euismod. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec sed
              odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kapil I was doing that but was running into the overlap issue with the footer and the body copy area. So you added the additional style of 50px padding to the bottom to correct that?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and couldn't find the solution for days. Then I learned flexbox. You can solve it by changing

```
<div class="card">...</div>
```

to

```
<div class="card h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">...</div>
```

It works with Bootstrap 4, I don't know about other versions.

Comment: Thanks for this! That was a great solution

Comment: This solution pushes the cards to use 100% of the viewport width with me which in my case was not what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

Or just use the correct Bootstrap classes, `card-body` instead of `card-block`

```css
.row {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Featured
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Featured
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada
              magna mollis euismod. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec sed
              odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this answer, It helped me solve the problem very easy. +1